# Perturbing image of function, general tube lemma

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

Assume $X,Y$ are compact Hausdorff spaces and that $f:X\times Y\rightarrow X\times Y'$ is an open, continuous function. Let $K\subseteq Y'$ be a closed subset.

Fix $a\in X$. Consider the function $\varphi_a: Y\rightarrow Y'$, given by $\varphi_a(y)=(\pi \circ f)(a,y)$. Here, $\pi$ denotes projection.

Assume $K\subseteq \varphi_a(Y)$ and that each $\varphi_x$ is open.

Show that there exists an open neighbourhood $N$ of $a$ such that for all $b\in N$, $K\subseteq \varphi_b(Y)$ .

My attempt:

Consider $a\times \varphi_a^{-1}(K)$. It is compact in $X\times Y$. Since $f$ is open, $\varphi_a(Y)$ is open in $Y'$. Hence, $f^{-1}(a\times \varphi_a(Y))$  is open in $X\times Y$.

Hence, $a\times \varphi_a^{-1}(K)\subseteq f^{-1}(a\times \varphi_a(Y)) \subseteq X\times Y$.

Choose open sets $V$ of a in $X$ and $W$ of $\varphi_a^{-1}(K)$  in $Y$ such that $a\times \varphi_a^{-1}(K)\subseteq V\times W \subseteq f^{-1}(a\times \varphi_a(Y))$

However, I am unable to complete the proof.

**Comments:**

[1] Choosing $V$ and $W$ as above follow from the general tube Lemma.

[2] K is closed implies in this case that $K$ is compact.

[3] $\varphi_a^{-1}(K)$  is closed in $Y$ and therefore also compact.

[4] $f$ is a closed map.

[5] $\varphi_a$ is both, an open and closed map.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't register it's an assumption. I'l delete my comments

Comment: "... each $\varphi_x$ is open". What is $x$? For all $x\in X$?

Comment: Yes @Apass.Jack